# Strange behaviour with NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
select count(distinct clean_deep_link) from tbl_1;
+---------------------------------+
| count(distinct clean_deep_link) |
+---------------------------------+
|                          121211 |
+---------------------------------+
```

I have this query :

```
select count(1) from tbl_1 where clean_deep_link IN
  (select clean_deep_link from tbl_2);

+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|    66360 |
+----------+
```

But when I change the query to `not in` it returns an empty set :

```
select count(1) from tbl_1
where clean_deep_link not in (select clean_deep_link from tbl_2);
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

How is this possible? if the subquery contains about half of the records, shouldn't the `not` of the subquery contain the other half? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Try `SELECT count(*), count(1) FROM tbl_1 ...`

Comment: Do you have nulls in the column? What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_1 WHERE clean_deep_link IS NULL` return?

Comment: Or in other words, there are three halfs in a SQL table.

Comment: @vyegorov - this still returns 0,0

Comment: @ypercube - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_1 WHERE clean_deep_link IS NULL` returns 0. there are no NULL's in there.

Comment: Please, show both table definitions.

Comment: You probably have messed up what you run and what you show. Please try this and post the results in the question: `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(clean_deep_link), COUNT(DISTINCT clean_deep_link), COUNT(clean_deep_link IS NULL) FROM tbl_1` (and then the same for `tbl_2`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would assume that `tbl_1.clean_deep_link` is `NULL` for the rest of the rows.

These values are neither `IN` nor `NOT IN` your sub-query.

---

The other reason could be, that you have `NULL` in `tbl_2.clean_deep_link`.

Please try the following:

```
select count(1) from tbl_1
where clean_deep_link not in (select clean_deep_link
                              from tbl_2 WHERE clean_deep_link IS NOT NULL);
```

The problem with `NULL` is that it is neither `=`, nor `<>` any other value (including `NULL`).

When checking for `NOT IN`, MySQL needs to check for each value in `tbl_1` that it is not contained in `tbl_2` and thus checks if they are `<>`.

Your values were **not** `<> NULL`, so they were **not** `NOT IN`.

See also: [Using NOT IN operator with null values](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/)

---

Check example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3de6a/3).

Comment: Yes, there was a single record in tbl_2 that had NULL for clean_deep_link... when I had removed that record, the subquery worked fine. How could that have caused it?

Comment: Tried to explain it in my recent update, hope it's not too confusing ;) Consider putting a `NOT NULL` constraint on `tbl_2.clean_deep_link` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I cant understand the rationale behind this, but I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `NULL` columns in MySQL are counted as being distinct, so three `NULL` values are all considered distinct.

As mentioned elsewhere, you can't compare `NULL` against other values using conventional comparison operators, amongst which `IN` and `NOT IN`.

The following operators can handle `NULL` values

```
x <=> y - returns 1 if x == y (even if both are NULL)
x IS NULL - returns 1 if x is null
x IS NOT NULL - returns 0 if x is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(1) 
FROM tbl_1 
WHERE clean_deep_link IN (
    SELECT clean_deep_link 
    FROM tbl_2
);
```